# Tableau with Vertica accented characters not displaying from VARCHAR field

Tags: character-encoding, vertica, tableau-api

I've created a data connection to a Vertica table from Tableau and have a 'surname1' field in the rows. This field exists as VARCHAR in Vertica and if doing a SELECT I can see accented characters in the command line no problem.

The problem is that in Tableau these are not represented correctly, and I can't find any way to change the field encoding in Tabelau to recognise them.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Below is an example of a select from Vertica in the command line, and what appears in Tableau:

```
surname1
---------------
Mérida
Fernández
Villadóniga
Muñoz
López
```

[image: Tableau Accented Character Error]

Thanks in advance,

James

Answer (score 2):

Just leaving this in case it helps anybody in the future:

The cause of the problem was that the Vertica database was being fed by a MySQL database through a mysqli connection. This connections character encoding was configured as latin1 / 8859-1, whereas Vertica was configured under utf-8.

The problem was then further confounded because the Putty window I was using to access Vertica from Windows was also configured under latin1 / 8859-1 which effectively rendered invisible the fact the data wasn't stored correctly in Vertica under utf-8.

To solve this, I reconfigured the mysqli that fed the vertica connection to use utf-8 encoding, with the following line of code:

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Note, to find out the characterset was Latin1 in the first place, I used the following:

```
echo $CMySQLI->character_set_name();
```

In summary, if you find an accented character problem with Tableau and your accessing your DB through putty, ensure the character encoding is aligned between putty and the DB so that errors aren't masked in this way.

Regards,

James